# Synonymize or retag [online] and [online-roleplaying]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We should synonymize or retag [online](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online) + [online-roleplaying](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-roleplaying) -> [online-roleplaying](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-roleplaying).

The tag wiki for [online](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online) reads:

> Involving play of tabletop RPGs using Internet tools such as desktop applications, web applications, chat clients, and so on.

Which fits the self-description of [online-roleplaying](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-roleplaying) exactly. I suggest we stick with [online-roleplaying](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-roleplaying), though, since it's more self-descriptive.

Comment: I actually favor [tag:online] as the base tag because [tag:online-roleplaying] is redundant wrt the site name

Comment: @wax I can accept that. It doesn't read as well, but I suppose makes more sense in context.

Comment: @waxeagle The advantage of using [[tag:online-roleplaying]] is that it will be obvious that it doesn't belong on questions like "Where can I find plot seeds online?"; it's not obvious that [[tag:online]] is inappropriate for that. I think the redundancy isn't actually there since not everything we talk about online is *online roleplaying*. I think it accurately describes the meaning of the tag.

Comment: @Seven That is also a good justification for a retag instead of a synonymization

Comment: Retagging without synonymising is a lot of work though. Since the tags meaning is identical, we should just have one and make the other a synonym.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe we instead need to split [online](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online) into [online-tools](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-tools) and [online-roleplaying](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-roleplaying).  Once that's done then we should synonym [online](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online) to [online-roleplaying](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-roleplaying), but if we don't pull out the tools questions first it'll make a hash of it.

Comment: Hmmm there's also a [tag:online-resources] that's kinda semi overlapping with the tools space.

Comment: OK here's what I did.  After review there were a lot of [tag:online-resources] tags also combined with [tag:tools] tags. So rather than make [tag:online-tools] I just tagged online resources with [tag:online-resources] and tools with [tag:online-resources] and [tag:tools] to get the same effect with less retagging.

Comment: I'm also synonyming [tag:online] to [tag:online-resources] instead of [tag:online-roleplaying] because there's 4x more questions in the former camp (and of the ones I retagged off [tag:online] the majority were tools q's).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, we should synonymize [online](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online) → [online-roleplaying](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-roleplaying), so that the main tag is [online-roleplaying](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-roleplaying).

The advantage of making [online-roleplaying](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-roleplaying) the main tag is that it will be obvious that it doesn't belong on questions like "Where can I find plot seeds online?", while it's not obvious that [online](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online) is inappropriate for that. I don't think there's any redundancy with our site's topic because not everything we roleplayers do online or talk about online is *online roleplaying*. I think "online-roleplaying" accurately represents the meaning of the tag in a way that "online" doesn't.

Comment: Hmm, seems like the online tagged questions break down into two major camps - trying to find an online tool, and issues/techniques with actually playing online. These seem different to me (otherwise questions about tabletop tools and tabletop techniques should also be merged, which I don't think anyone would propose). I think both an online-tools and online-roleplaying tag might be better.

Comment: @mxyzplk We definitely have two uses of it, yeah. I'm not sure we need to distinguish online and offline tools, but I don't play online so I mistrust my opinion on that. :)